# Visual Basic in Word 2010 - Open Dir - Relative Path

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I'm creating a word document and I'm having trouble working out the code to open a specific directory.
Basically, I'll have a bunch of video files on a USB drive or a DVD in separate folders and when the command button is clicked, I would like it to open the relevant directory in a windows explorer window.

I did some Google searching and came up with the following code:

FolderName =  "c:\windows"

TaskID = Shell("explorer.exe " & FolderName, vbNormalFocus)

The only problem now is that I need to change the path reference from absolute to relative, as I'll be running everything from either a USB drive or a DVD on multiple computers.

I have tried every possible iteration of relative path references, but I can't seem to get it to work. The folders are simply sub-directories of where the word document is.

Anyone got any clues as how I can change the above code to be relative rather than absolute path references?

Comment: Why would you want to do this using MS Word?

Comment: I'm doing an assignment and it's the way I've decided to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
FolderName = ActiveDocument.Path & "\SubFolder"

TaskID = Shell("explorer.exe " & FolderName, vbNormalFocus)
```

Assuming that your document is the active one, otherwise you might need to search through the `Documents` collection for the correct one.